# SocialEngine4 - Twitter Follow button

Tags: php, socialengine, twitter-follow, twitter-button

I am using SocialEngine4 and trying to integrate Twitter Follow Button in it. But it is not showing button so user will get login screen onclick of it.

I checked its script code and found mootool is used.  SocialEngine4 also using mootool. So due to some conflict twitter button is not generating properly.

I tried code of this button in plan php and it is working fine.

Does anyone have idea about it ? I am using following code to generate twitter button

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/mysite" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-dnt="true">Follow @Geschaeftspart</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go this the [Add this](https://www.addthis.com/login?next=%2Fdashboard)
its work beautifully with socialengine.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, We can add Twitter button. But for my requirement, I want set of Twitter, LinkedIn and Facebook buttons that not meet here.